# Page Object Model seeing null pointer exception when running my tests?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

When triggering my test I seem to be seeing a null pointer exception when trying to interact with my `Page Factory` `WebElement`.

Code contained within my `DriverFactory`:

```
public class DriverFactory {
    private static DriverFactory instance = null;
    public static ThreadLocal<WebDriver> webDriver = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>();

    public static DriverFactory getInstance() {
        if ( instance == null ) {
            instance = new DriverFactory();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public static final void setDriver(String browser) {
        switch (browser) {

        case "firefox":
                System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", 
                Global_VARS.FIREFOX_DRIVER_DIRECTORY);
                webDriver.set(new FirefoxDriver());
            break;

        case "chrome":
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
                Global_VARS.CHROME_DRIVER_DIRECTORY);
                webDriver.set(new ChromeDriver());
            break;
        }
        getDriver().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        getDriver().manage().window().maximize();
    }

    public static WebDriver getDriver() {
        return webDriver.get();
    }

    public static void tearDown() {
        getDriver().quit();
    }
}
```

Code contained within my `base` page:

```
public abstract class BasePO<T>  {
    private @FindBy(xpath = "//a[text()='Log in']") WebElement logIn_button;
    protected WebDriver driver;

    public BasePO() {
        this.driver = DriverFactory.getDriver();
        PageFactory.initElements(this.driver, this);
    }

    public void openHomepage() {
        driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/");
    }

    public void baseClickOnLoginButton() {
        logIn_button.click();
    }
}
```

Code contained within my `BaseTest` class:

```
public class BaseTest {
    public SubPage subPage;
    public BasePO<?> basePage;

    @BeforeClass
    public void pomSetup() {
        subPage = PageFactory.initElements(DriverFactory.getDriver(), SubPage.class);
        basePage = PageFactory.initElements(DriverFactory.getDriver(), BasePO.class);
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setup() {
        DriverFactory.setDriver("chrome");

        //works
        //subPage.openHomepage();
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() {
        if (DriverFactory.getDriver() != null) {
            DriverFactory.tearDown();
        }
    }
```

The code which form's my Test case:

```
public class Test1 extends BaseTest {
    @Test
    public void exampleTest1() throws InterruptedException {
        subPage.openHomepage(); //works as expected

        subPage.clickOnLoginButton(); //Exception here, null pointer 
    }
}
```

When trigger my `TestNg` test its the `openHomePage` method works, in turn opening the specified url; which uses `DriverFactory.getDriver().get()`  however when attempting to click on a `Page Factory` element such as calling: `logIn_button.click();` within my test I seem to be receiving a null pointer exception even though I have initialised the class?

Comment: You're doing a PageFactory.InitElements in both the BasePO class and the BaseTest class.

Comment: PageFactory for abstract class ? i'am getting confused

Comment: You cannot call `PageFactory.initElements(DriverFactory.getDriver(), BasePO.class)`, because BasePO is **abstract** class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the @BeforeClass, you have initialized the Page factory before you created the driver instance. If you move the code in `pomSetup()` to the `setup()` method after the `DriverFactory.setDriver("chrome");` the test code should work. Also, in the `BasePO` class you have initialized the page factory in the constructor, so calling new in the `BaseTest` Class will be enough.

```
@BeforeClass
public void pomSetup() {

}

@BeforeMethod
public void setup() {
    DriverFactory.setDriver("chrome");
    // Page factory initialized the constructor of BasePO class
    subPage = new SubPage();
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Sighil!

Comment: @Sighil, do you by any chance know the answer to this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67067486/why-is-a-pagefactory-class-returning-null-when-initialised-from-another-class/67081667#67081667

Answer (score 0):

On the code part, a couple of suggestions.

- The implementation of the DriveFactory is wrong. You are using a singleton initialization which is never used. Instead change the code to below.

  ```
  public class DriverFactory {
      private static DriverFactory instance = null;
      // Singleton initialization
      public static DriverFactory getInstance() {
          if ( instance == null ) 
              instance = new DriverFactory();
          return instance;
      }

      public ThreadLocal<WebDriver> webDriver = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>();

      public final void setDriver(String browser) {
          switch (browser) {
              case "firefox":
                  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", Global_VARS.FIREFOX_DRIVER_DIRECTORY);
                  webDriver.set(new FirefoxDriver());
                  break;
              case "chrome":
                  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", Global_VARS.CHROME_DRIVER_DIRECTORY);
                  webDriver.set(new ChromeDriver());
                  break;
          }
          getDriver().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
          getDriver().manage().window().maximize();
      }

      public WebDriver getDriver() {
          return webDriver.get();
      }

      public void tearDown() {
          getDriver().quit();
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: @Sigil thank you again for your help, really appreciate it