# Why is a pagefactory class returning null when initialised from another class

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium, page-factory

In my test class, I have `DesiredCapabilities` set up for Appium test. In that class, I initialised my BasePage class holding `pagefactory` elements. When I run the test, it works as expected.

Now, I tried to be a bit more creative by moving my DediredCapabilities into a separate class, `CapacityManager`. In my test class, I called the method holding the DesiredCapabilities from the CapacityManager. The method call was successful, my app was launched, but the `pagefactory` elements were no longer working. I am not sure why.

When I run the test, I get a nullPointerExceptio on the first mobile element and this makes me suspect that a `pagefactory` or driver initialisation problem.

The working test class looks like this:

```
public class LoginTest {
    
      private final BaseUtil baseUtil = new BaseUtil();
      private static BasePage basePage;
      public static AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver;
      public static File classpathRoot;
    
    
      public void startApp() throws MalformedURLException {
        classpathRoot = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        File appDir = new File(classpathRoot, "");
        File app = new File(appDir, baseUtil.getMyApp());
        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "11.0");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Android Emulator");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "uiautomator2");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, app.getAbsolutePath());
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub");
        driver = new AndroidDriver<>(url, cap);
        basePage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, BasePage.class); //pagefactory initialised
      }
    
    
    
      public void login(String sheetname, int rowNumber) throws InterruptedException, IOException, InvalidFormatException {
        FeatureUtils featureUtils = new FeatureUtils();
        File excelDir = new File(classpathRoot, "");
        File exceldoc = new File(excelDir, baseUtil.getUsersExcelDoc());
        List<Map<String, String>> testData = featureUtils.getData(exceldoc.getAbsolutePath(), sheetname);
        String username = testData.get(rowNumber).get("username");
        String password = testData.get(rowNumber).get("password");
  
        basePage.yesIAgreeButton.click(); //first element clicks successfully
```

This is the BasePage class holding the `pagefactory` elements:

```
    public class BasePage {
    
      private final WebDriver driver;

      public BasePage(WebDriver driver) { //constructor
        this.driver = driver;
      }
    
     
      @FindBy(id = "com.test")
  public WebElement yesIAgreeButton;
```

With the two classes above, the LoginTest class works as expected.

Now, I removed the DesiredCapabilities from the test class and put them in a new class, `CapacityManager`:

```
public class CapacityManager {

  public static AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver;
  public static File classpathRoot;
  private final BaseUtil baseUtil = new BaseUtil();
  private static BasePage basePage;

  public DesiredCapabilities appDesiredCapabilities() throws MalformedURLException {
    DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = null;
    classpathRoot = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    File appDir = new File(classpathRoot, "");
    File app = new File(appDir, baseUtil.getMyApp());
    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "11.0");
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Android Emulator");
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "uiautomator2");
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, app.getAbsolutePath());
    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub");
    driver = new AndroidDriver<>(url, cap);
    basePage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, BasePage.class); //pagefactory initialisation

    return desiredCapabilities;
  }
   
}
```

I then called the `DesiredCapabilities` from the test class, like this:

```
 public class LoginTest {
    
      private final BaseUtil baseUtil = new BaseUtil();
      private static BasePage basePage;
      public static AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver;
      public static File classpathRoot;
      CapacityManager capacityManager = new CapacityManager();
    
     
      public void startApp() throws MalformedURLException {
    capacityManager.appDesiredCapabilities();  //method call. App launches successfully.
    }
    
      
    
      public void login(String sheetname, int rowNumber) throws InterruptedException, IOException, InvalidFormatException {
        FeatureUtils featureUtils = new FeatureUtils();
        File excelDir = new File(classpathRoot, "");
        File exceldoc = new File(excelDir, baseUtil.getUsersExcelDoc());
        List<Map<String, String>> testData = featureUtils.getData(exceldoc.getAbsolutePath(), sheetname);
        String username = testData.get(rowNumber).get("username");
        String password = testData.get(rowNumber).get("password");

       basePage.yesIAgreeButton.click(); //getting nullpointer error on this line. Looks like an issue with the pagefactory elements initialisation. basePage is null.
       driver.pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.TAB));
```

Answer (score 3):

The `basePage` inside of `CapacityManager` and the one inside `LoginTest` are two different objects instances and the one inside `LoginTest` was never initialized. All you need to do is something like this:

```
basePage = capacityManager.getBasePage(); // create this method returning basePage object
basePage.yesIAgreeButton.click();
```

Or... since `basePage` is `static`, make it public and call it statically `CapacityManager.basePage`. That said, I don't think any of those `static` fields should be `static`.

#### UPDATE

The class `CapacityManager` is poorly constructed. For starters, it has private static fields that are never used for anything after being initialized. I won't fix everything, but I would fix what pertains to this post. Replace `CapacityManager` with my version and update to fix the issue with the other fields.

```
public class CapacityManager {

  public AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver;
  public File classpathRoot;
  private final BaseUtil baseUtil = new BaseUtil();
  private BasePage basePage;
  private DesiredCapabilities cap;
  private File app;

  public CapacityManager() {
    classpathRoot = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    File appDir = new File(classpathRoot, "");
    app = new File(appDir, baseUtil.getMyApp());
  }

  public DesiredCapabilities appDesiredCapabilities() throws MalformedURLException {
    if (cap == null) {
        cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "11.0");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Android Emulator");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "uiautomator2");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, app.getAbsolutePath());
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub");
        driver = new AndroidDriver<>(url, cap);
    }

    return cap;
  }

  public BasePage getBasePage() {
      return basePage;
  }
}
```

Without changing anything else in the `LoginTest` class (I assume it works "correctly"), simply get the BasePage by calling the getter method:

```
public void login(String sheetname, int rowNumber) throws InterruptedException, IOException, InvalidFormatException {
    FeatureUtils featureUtils = new FeatureUtils();
    File excelDir = new File(classpathRoot, "");
    File exceldoc = new File(excelDir, baseUtil.getUsersExcelDoc());
    List<Map<String, String>> testData = featureUtils.getData(exceldoc.getAbsolutePath(), sheetname);
    String username = testData.get(rowNumber).get("username");
    String password = testData.get(rowNumber).get("password");

    BasePage basePage = PageFactory.initElements(capacityDriver.driver, BasePage.class); // pass the AndroidDriver instance in CapacityDriver class
    basePage.clickYesIAgree();
}
```

#### UPDATE #2

Typically, when you create a factory to provide instances of a class, you hide the constructor of that class. When you have public constructors of a class, sometimes is better not to have a factory. Why? To avoid confusion. Of course, there are plenty of exceptions to what I just mentioned. Here, we have one of those confusing implementations.

You have a `BasePage` with a public constructor that takes a `WebDriver` as an argument. You also have `PageFactory.initElements(driver, BasePage.class)` that returns an instance of `BasePage`. How should I create an instance of `BasePage`? When should the factory be used? When should I call the contructor directly?

Considering that `PageFactory` is a proven class provided by the Selenium library, it is reasonable to believe that `BasePage` is ill contructed and/or the use of the `@FindBy` annotation is incorrect. None of those I can fix for you, but I can suggest what I believe `BasePage` should look like. Here you go:

```
public class BasePage {
    @FindBy(id = "com.test") // this component ID looks suspicious
    private WebElement yesIAgreeButton;

    public void clickYesIAgree() {
        yesIAgreeButton.click();
    }
}
```

The previous code has been updated after this second update.

Comment: @Theman The code you have is a mess. I will repost my answer fixing what you originally posted.

Comment: thanks. I made a good progress with your update, `basePage`is now fully initialised, however, driver is null. I should have included the first occurrence of the driver object in my question. My bad. I have updated the question. Basically, after `basePage.yesIAgreeButton.click()`, there is a driver call `driver.pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.TAB));` which is null. How do I initialise it?

Comment: @Theman you need to keep your object instances under control. You are creating objects all over the place for no good reason. For example, you have a `driver` fully instantiated in `CapacityManager` but you are calling a method in `BasePage` that calls `click()`. Based on that, I am assuming that you have another (null) `driver` object inside that class. Decide where you want to store objects, fully initialize them there, and then provide accessor methods so that these object instances can be shared and used properly.

Comment: Thanks, @hfontanez, that's is exactly what I am trying to do. I would appreciate if you could update your answer with the driver instantiation. I like the way you have approached the implementation

Comment: @Theman I don't know what `PageFactory` looks like, but I will do my best based on what you have posted.

Comment: You have tried your best, @hfontanez. Thanks, but the driver is still null with the new implementation. I will just leave it for now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231130/discussion-between-the-man-and-hfontanez).

Answer (score 1):

Objects represent real world entities. For example (taking a page out of the Head First Java reference), a cat is an object. A cat has legs and mouth as features which can be used for doing certain things like running and biting.

Likewise when you created the `CapacityManager` class and called `new` operator on it in the `LoginTest`, you have created an object. `CapacityManager` has `driver`, and `BasePage` (among other features) using which you have initialized in the `appDesiredCapabilities()` method.

In the case of the Cat, we cannot use the cat's legs to run and use the cat's mouth to bite (there is obviously a way to do this in java but we are getting ahead of ourselves at this point). We can tell the cat to run and bite but in the end the cat has to do these operations by itself. Likewise, `CapacityManager` features like `driver` and `BasePage` cannot be used by us from outside the `CapacityManager`. We can call the `CapacityManager.appDesiredCapabilities()` method to initialize the driver, and set page factory on `BasePage` but we cannot use them directly.

Simply put, declaring `driver` and `BasePage` in the `LoginTest` and creating an object of `CapacityManager` does not initialize the `driver` and `BasePage` features in the `LoginTest`. We have to figure out how to control the `driver` and `BasePage` declared in the `CapacityManager` in `LoginTest`. For this we use `public` access modifier in the `CapacityManager` for `driver` and `BasePage`. The correct OOPs way is to use `getters` to make the features public so that we can get access to them from outside. This is shown in the below code update.

```
public class CapacityManager {

    private DesiredCapabilities cap;
    private AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver;
    private BasePage basePage;

    public CapacityManager() {
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub");
        this.cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "11.0");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Android Emulator");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, "uiautomator2");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, app.getAbsolutePath());
        this.driver = new AndroidDriver<>(url, cap);
        this.basePage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, BasePage.class);
    }

    public AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

    public BasePage getBasePage() {
        return basePage;
    }

}


public class LoginTest {

    private File classpathRoot;
    private BaseUtil baseUtil;
    private File app;

    // Launch the app, initialize driver and page factory
    CapacityManager capacityManager = new CapacityManager();

    public void login(String sheetname, int rowNumber)
            throws InterruptedException, IOException, InvalidFormatException {
        // Intialize file objects
        baseUtil = new BaseUtil();
        classpathRoot = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        app = new File(new File(classpathRoot, ""), baseUtil.getMyApp());

        FeatureUtils featureUtils = new FeatureUtils();
        File excelDir = new File(capacityManager.classpathRoot, "");
        File exceldoc = new File(excelDir, baseUtil.getUsersExcelDoc());
        List<Map<String, String>> testData = featureUtils.getData(exceldoc.getAbsolutePath(), sheetname);
        String username = testData.get(rowNumber).get("username");
        String password = testData.get(rowNumber).get("password");

        // Get driver and BasePage from capacityManager object
        capacityManager.getBasePage().yesIAgreeButton.click(); 
        capacityManager.getDriver().pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.TAB));
    }
}
```

There are a lot of different and better ways to configure this. If you are feeling even more fancy, you can create a class for getting the testdata. That is for another day.

Hopefully the solution above will solve the error you are getting!